# Specific matrix decomposition

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition, symmetric-matrices, unipotent-matrices

Suppose we have a symmetric matrix $A$. Is it possible to find unipotent matrix $U$ and diagonal matrix $D$ such that $U A U^T = D$?